# Django- Check the filetype of an uploaded file and then alter the template

Tags: python, django

I want to write a function that checks the extension of the uploaded file and depending on that assigns a variable a value.
I hope it makes sense. I basically want to check the filetype of an uploaded file and then alter the template accordingly.
The code that I am thinking of implementing is something like this but I am kind of confused

## models.py

```
class ScribbleMedia(models.Model):
         media = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
         typecheck=find_typecheck
         def __unicode__(self):
          return self.media
```

## but I don't know where to write this function

```
def find_typecheck(instance, filename):
        label=filename
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        if ext == 'jpeg':
            a=1
        else:
            a=2
        return a
```

## in html template I should be able to do this

```
{% if ScribbleMedia.typecheck ==1 %}
    do something
{% else %}
    do something else
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put that method in your model class and use that in template to get the type of file. You can call this method using the instance of `ScribbleMedia`.

e.g.

```
class ScribbleMedia(models.Model):
     media = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.media
     def find_typecheck(self):
        filename = self.media.name
        try:
           ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
           if ext == 'jpeg':
              a=1
           else:
              a=2
        except Exception:
           a=-1 #couldn't determine
        return a
```

In template:

```
{% if sc_media_obj.find_typecheck ==1 %}
    do something
{% else %}
    do something else
{% endif %}
```

On side note: Checking for just file extensions may not be sufficient.

Comment: thank you so much Rohan. it worked! :)

but what did you mean by Checking for just file extensions may not be sufficient?

Comment: @sankaet, I can upload mis_named_file.jpeg, but which is not actually a picture but text file.

Comment: that's true. is there a way to deal situations like that?

Comment: but jpeg was just an example, I have a bunch of file types that I want to upload. like pdf doc etc